# Find the minimal polynomial of a root involving cubed roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

I've been searching around stack exchange trying to find a good example on this but most of them seem to require less calculation than this one seems to take.

> Find the minimal polynomial of $1+\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4$ over $\mathbb Q$.

The way I've been approaching it is 
$$x=1+\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4\Rightarrow x-1-\sqrt[3]2=\sqrt[3]4$$
then cubing both sides and working from there but it seems to take an awful lot of calculation. Is there a quicker way? I also tried to reverse engineer an answer by checking it on Wolfram Alpha but I think they gave me the wrong answer ($x^3-3x^2-3x-1$) because it wasn't working out for me. But maybe I just did the calculations wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that
$$1+\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4=\frac{2-1}{\sqrt[3]2-1}=\frac1{\sqrt[3]2-1}$$
The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]2$ is $x^3-2$. That of $\sqrt[3]2-1$ can be found by substituting $x\to x+1$: $(x+1)^3-2=x^3+3x^2+3x-1$. The minimal polynomial of the original expression is then obtained by reversing the coefficients (to effect the reciprocal): $-x^3+3x^2+3x+1$ or $x^3-3x^2-3x-1$. Wolfram Alpha is right on this one.

Comment: great answer :) thanks a million. but would you mind elaborating a little on how you affected the reciprocal ?

Comment: @exodius See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078606/357390). If you have that $p(r)=0$ where $p$ is a polynomial in $x$, then you can substitute $x\to\frac1x$ and multiply by $x^n$ where $n$ is the polynomial degree to get a polynomial $q(x)$ with $\frac1r$ as a root.

Comment: but how did you just change two of the signs to get the minimal polynomial of the original expression ?

Comment: @exodius I did not just change two signs. I negated the whole polynomial to get a monic one.

Comment: ohhhh i see , sorry i'm super tired XD

Comment: ....accepted :)

Comment: How does the first equality follow? Why did you do this? What motivated it? It seems very artificial.